# How to synchronize two tables in an Oracle database?

Tags: java, database, oracle

Two different systems have a table in a database that stores users. The first system is the one who has from time to time (once daily) to synchronize and complement your table with the users of those in the second table. (deleted, updated, added)

I thought about starting something like "job" in a database that will perform such a synchronization.

I have a question about how best to carry out such a project synchronization. The easiest way was to remove all users in the system and throw the first time on the day of the second system.

But I would prefer that it be performed incrementally, which would have only those users who have been added or removed at the time and only update the tables on them with the first system.

How best to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Oracle 11g you can use DBMS_COMPARISON – compare and synchronize tables.

Take a look here: http://technology.amis.nl/blog/2420/dbms_comparison-to-compare-and-synchronize-tables-new-in-oracle-11g

Answer (score 0):

See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028089/efficient-method-to-sync-up-two-tables-in-different-server-with-java) for answers if you want to do it using Java.